# class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter error in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-security

I used spring security for the login of my application. I used Maven, Spring Boot 3.2.3 and Java 17. I have got below error when Compilation of my project.

```
java: cannot find symbol  

symbol:   class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

  location: package org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration
```

It says cannot find `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` I have added the dependencies also but still I am getting that error

I'm using **intelliji** as IDE.Below I have provide the code i tried to use Spring security

```
package com.xyz.productdashboardlogin;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
}
```

And also below i will provide my `Pom.xml` file.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>Product-Dashboard-Login</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Product-Dashboard-Login</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Are the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` not working with newer versions of Spring?
I'm a beginner to the Spring Boot. Could you please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Is it a compilation error or runtime? Please post the error logs as well.

Comment: That's a compilation error. It displays WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in red color. The error says 'Cannot resolve symbol 'WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter''

Comment: My bad... You are right. It has been removed in Spring 3.x

Comment: You can try alternate ways to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: Yes I am using IntelliJ. I tried invalidate cache. but issue is not fixed. Still getting same issue

Comment: [Spring Security without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring Security 5.7.0, Spring deprecated the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.
It encourages a component-based security configuration.